# Xamarin Error - aapt.exe/resources

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin, cross-platform

Instalei o VisualStudio 2015 Community, com o Xamarin, até ai beleza.

Mas estou com problemas, na verdade não só eu, vi em vários lugares, que bastante gente está com os mesmos erros.Infelizmente eu não consegui achar a solução ainda, espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

> Diretório Android SDK:
>
> C:\users\fd\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
>
> Diretório JDK:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
>
> Diretório NDK:
>
> C:\Users\fd\Documents\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r10e

Eu estou com os seguintes erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nos forums que eu vi, o erro "aapt.exe", eles estavam falando que poderia ser algum arquivo de imagem que tem um "-" no nome do arquivo, isso não é, porque não tem nenhum arquivo com "traço" no projeto.

Outra coisa que eu li também, é que se atualizasse todos os packages do Android SDK Manager, esse erro seria solucionado, já fiz isso, e o erro continua.

Os outros erros, eu não achei nada sobre eles ainda.

Também estava com problema, no arquivo `Resources.Designer.cs`, nesse arquivo estava gerando mais de 2 mil erros, eu comentei tudo, e o erro sumiu...

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Segue os passos abaixo para identificar o problema:

1 -  **No Visual studio**: Tools > Options > Projects and solutions > Build and Run.

1.1 - **No dropdown**: MSBuild project build output verbosity: > Diagnostic.

1.2 - Feche a caixa de dialogo.

2 - View > Output (Ctrl+W, O).

3 - Execute o build ou rebuild.

No output encontre pela linha:

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1665,3):
>   error MSB6006: "aapt.exe" exited with code 1."

O que está logo acima deste erro é o que causou o erro.

Comment: Valeu pela dica Tiago, eu já havia feito isso, e não conseguia a solução. Postei no forum do Xamarin, e um cara me respondeu, pedindo pra baixar a última versão do JDK e a última versão do SDK, baixei, e compilou. Mas agora, eu não estou conseguindo rodar o projeto, eu preciso rodar no Hyper-V ?

Comment: Você precisa ter um emulador ou um dispositivo para executar o projeto, caso contrario ele não executa

Comment: O Emulador pode ser o Hyper-V, entretanto, na minha maquina eu ainda não consegui executar o emulador do android...

Comment: Entendi. Aqui esta aparecendo no AVD, mas eu não consigo "startar", vou tentar baixar um emulador pra testar, valeu cara!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui, o meu problema era o mesmo.
Criei um arquivo portable, e logo fui testa se todos os Cross estariam funcionando.
o Android dava esse erro, no SDK manager notei que tinha 2 SDK 24 intalado.
o SDK Build-TOOLS 24 e SDK Plataform Tools 24.
removi o SDK Build e deixei o Plataform.
Resolvido aqui.