# Problemas com Xamarin no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou começando a "brincar" com desenvolvimento mobile e como já desenvolvo em C#, tive vontade de usar o Xamarin. Mas, logo que instalei e atualize/instalei tudo que tinha no SDK manager do android. Tive as seguintes mensagens de erro no deploy, inicialmente:

- "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
- The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.

Realizando as correções que foram passadas, consegui iniciar o emulador, mas surgiu novos erros:

- 1>The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe" is invalid.
- 1>The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.

Alguém?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Xamarin Error - aapt.exe/resources](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125308/xamarin-error-aapt-exe-resources)

Comment: Fiz o que foi passado e "consegui" novos erros...